# Using CSS to customize ioslides in R

Tags: css, r, fonts, ioslides

To begin with, I am just using the default ioslides presentation in R. At the moment, trying to figure out how to accomplish 3 items

1. Make the space between the header and the text smaller.
2. How to decrease the font size in the body
3. How to decrease font size in the header

As of yet, this is my attempt. No errors but nothing has changed. I am under the impression that ## equates to h2. Am I incorrect?

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
 h2{
font-family:'Arial';
font-size:'10';
padding-bottom:1px;
}

body{
font-family:'Arial';
font size:'8';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Question: I did'nt understand

2.Question

```
body{
font-size:8px;
}
```

3.Question:

```
    h2{
font-size:10px;
}
```

Comment: 1.Question: Normally there is margin in h2, there is not padding. Maybe you can try to change margin value. For example:
h2{margin:1px;}

Comment: Kalayci, I have this .css file in the same directory as my Rmd (ioslides) and when I knit, nothing changes.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know ioslides, maybe you should use "!important" like this: h2{font-size: 10px !important;}
if it doesn't work i can't help sorry :/